# gcc : undefined reference to 'function'

Tags: c, gcc, linker-errors, undefined-reference

I have installed a C library on my computer (Ubuntu) called `xx`, whose header file is at `/usr/local/include/xx/xx.h` and the `.a file` and `.so file` are in the path `/usr/local/lib` named `libxx.a` and `libxx.so`.

**The test file:**

```
#include<xx/xx.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
 printf("Test\n");
 call_function_declared_in_the_header_file();
 return 0;
}
```

When I use gcc to compile **gcc test.c -o test**, I get the following error:

```
/tmp/ccb7O0eh.o: In function `main':
test.c:(.text+0xa): undefined reference to `call_function_declared_in_the_header_file'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I don't know why. I am not good at the C language. So how can I fix it?

Comment: `call_function_defined_in_the_header_file()` is probably just *declared* (not *defined*) in `xx/xx.h`.

Comment: **how** is it *defined* in the header?

Comment: Add an option to tell the linker to look for the library.  Since you library names are not `libxx.a` and `libxx.so`, you’ll have to supply their path. Better to rename them so you can use `-lxx`.

Comment: Use `-L` to specify the library path and `-l` to name the library in that path to search (at least, those are the gcc options).

Comment: `call_function_declared_in_the_header_file(param)`

Comment: @jonathan-leffler[https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler] writing wrong,I have edit it again. They are sure named `libxx.a` and `libxx.so`.

Comment: So add `-lxx` to the command line that links the program — at the end, after all the object (and/or source) files listed on the command line.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler Thanks,It works.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler If I use cmake,so how can I set the option in CMakeLists.txt?

Answer (score 1):

you have to *link against* the library, i.e. if you want to include `<math.h>` ( `libm.so` / `libm.a`  ) you have to link against :

`gcc program.c -o program -lm` where the `-lm` invokes the linking

see http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_17.html,

https://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-l.html

compiling always involves the *compiler* and the *linker*